How to transition a Linux hard drive to be a virtual machine?
I had a PC running as a home server with the hard drive running Debian Linux alongside CasaOS and other things these past few months.
Things are different now, I have a far better PC running Windows, so I figured I'll throw the hard drive in here and find a way to use one computer for two things. But for some reason when I try to find a way to link that drive to a virtual machine bottle in a sense, I get an error Failed to load partitions for device \\.\PhysicalDrive0: Insufficient permission to access file. or something else like I can't see the drives showing up in my file explorer even though they say online in disk management and windows disk settings.
I've tried to switch VM’s, decrypt my drive, make a VHD file, nothing works. I don’t know what's going on and I've searched YouTube and asked ChatGPT and other AI's for help, nothing.

Which virtual machine software have your tried?

@DavidAnderson vmware, virtual box
